# How to load a list on page startup with user_id using useEffect

Tags: reactjs, use-effect, use-state

I have been truing to load a list on a page from the user_id that i get from the parent page, but I keep getting a **React Hook useEffect has a missing dependency: 'newuser_id'. Either include it or remove the dependency array react-hooks/exhaustive-deps** warning and then an error saying **Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined** now it doesn't even read the useEffect anymore..

This is my file:

```
import React, {useEffect, useState} from 'react';
import { authenticationService } from '../../services/authentication.service';

export default function Kilometer({user_id}) {
  const [kmListe, setKmListe] = useState([]);
  const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(false);
  const [error, setError] = useState(false);
  
  console.log('root ' + user_id);

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log('useEffect' + user_id)
    setIsLoading(true)
    if(!user_id){
      setKmListe('')
      console.log('!user_id ' + kmListe)
    }else{
      const getData = async () => {
      await authenticationService.kmliste(user_id)
      .then(
        km => {
          console.log('test 1 '+JSON.stringify(km))
          setKmListe(JSON.stringify(km))
          setIsLoading(false)
        }
      ).catch(err => {
        console.log('catch ' + err)
        setError(true)
        setIsLoading(false)
      })};
    getData()
    }
    
  }, [kmListe])
  const liste = 
  setIsLoading(true)
    if(kmListe === ''){
      console.log('blank '+kmListe)
      return ['No list','add km to make a list'];
    }else{
    kmListe.map(listen =>{
      console.log('map ' + listen)
    return(
        <div key={listen.id}>                    
                <div>
                    <h1>{listen.km_start} {listen.km_slut}</h1>
                    <h2>{listen.start_by} {listen.slut_by}</h2>  
                </div>
        </div>
    )
})}
console.log('return '+liste)
     return error ? 
<h1>{error}</h1> :
         isLoading ? 
        <h1>LOADING.......</h1> :
         liste.length ? <h1>{error}</h1> : (
            <div>
              {liste}
    </div>
        );
    
}
```

I have kept the console.logs in the code so you can see from my output on the console what is run

> root 2

> return undefined

> root 2

> return undefined

**EDIT**
Now no matter what I do useEffect doesn't fire at all, I stuck and I don't know how to get past it.
I have tried to remove the newuser_id and I have tried making a new page but same result..

Answer (score 1):

A couple of problems in this component.

- `useEffect` must accept a function without parameters. Something like `() => { /* effect*/ }`. By passing `newuser_id`, it overshadows the variable declared earlier in the code. Therefore, remove it from the parameter and pass it in the dependency array. By the way, why are you even declaring `newuser_id` instead of using `user_id` directly?
- `setKmListe` schedules an update. `kmListe` is not updated right away.

Comment: Okay when I remove newuser_id/user_id I get the warning as mentioned above and when I remove it now it still doesn't enter the useEffect, the reason for newuser_id was just to check that it came in @RodrigoAmaral

Answer (score 0):

The warning mentions the hook dependencies. Not sure if that will fix all your problems, but I feel it is a good start.

The dependencies are defined as the second parameter of the `useEffect` hook.

Example:

```js
useEffect(() => {
  const fetchUser = async () => {
    const response = await fetch(`http://something.com/users/%{userId}`);
    const user = await response.json();
    setUser(user);
  };
  if (userId) fetchUser();
}, [userId])
```

Notice that `userId` is part of the `useEffect` hook dependencies.

The general rule is to not lie about the dependencies. Means that if something is defined outside of your `useEffect`, but used inside, it should be part of the dependencies.

Read more [here](https://overreacted.io/a-complete-guide-to-useeffect/)

Also, `kmListe` being a hook dependency is an infinite loop waiting to happen because you redefine the state inside the hook. Every time the state is changed, since it is part of the dependencies, the effect will run again, and again on every render.